# select from database order by mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to ordonate some things in oder by date, but the query that should select the articles doesn't work. I have an issue with where and order by.

What i've tried:

```
  $query = mysql_query("select * from my_article where id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['idArticle]';?>' order by date") ;
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: php tag inside php tag

Comment: `<?php
$id = $_SESSION['idArticle];
$query = mysql_query("select * from my_article where id = $id order by date") ;`  and still `mysql_*`. Move to `mysqli_*` OR `PDO`. use back ticks around `date` in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***A Suggestion:-***

Regarding `mysql_*`:-

Deprecated from `php5.5` onward

Removed from `php7.0`.

So use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`(with `prepared statements`).

***Current solution:-***

```
<?php 
  $id = $_SESSION['idArticle']; // here `'` is missed in your question code
  $query = mysql_query("select * from my_article where id = $id order by `date`") ;
```

Comment: thanks for marking. please up-vote the answer too.thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  $query = mysql_query("select * from my_article where id='".$_SESSION['idArticle']."' order by date") ;
```

You can try this. You need to think sql injection ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure data type of date field is not varchar.